# How to bind Obj-C #define UMLOG_ERROR @"[UM Error] " with MonoTouch

Tags: c#, objective-c, ios, binding, xamarin.ios

Im new in MonoTouch. I am currently trying to bind an Objective-C library into MonoTouch, so far I've done much of the work, however, i don't know how to bind the following code :

```
static inline NSString* UmRet_lookup(UmRet c) {
#define URLOOK(a) case a: return @#a;
switch (c) {
    URLOOK(UMRET_SUCCESS          )
    URLOOK(UMRET_NO_READER        )
    URLOOK(UMRET_SDK_BUSY         )
    URLOOK(UMRET_ALREADY_CONNECTED)
    URLOOK(UMRET_NOT_CONNECTED    )
    URLOOK(UMRET_LOW_VOLUME       )
    URLOOK(UMRET_UF_INVALID_STR   )
    URLOOK(UMRET_UF_NO_FILE       )
    URLOOK(UMRET_UF_INVALID_FILE  )
    default: return @"<unknown code>";
    }
    #undef URLOOK
}
```

And also the next code :

```
#define UMLOG_ERROR    @"[UM Error] "
#define UMLOG_WARNING  @"[UM Warning] "
#define UMLOG_INFO     @"[UM Info] "
```

Comment: Why are you using a switch-case that way?

Comment: This is a third party objective-c library that I'm trying to bind into monotouch, that's the way it's been written, it's part of a header file in the original code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot bind this as it's not *really* Objective-C code but some C **pre**-processor directives.

In such cases you need to rewrite this into C#. This looks to be some translation of error codes into string representation. Depending on your app you might want to use C# strings (instead of `NSString`).

```
static public NSString UmRet_lookup (UmRet c)
{
   switch (c) {
   case UMRET_SUCCESS : return new NSString ("UMRET_SUCCESS");
   case UMRET_NO_READER : return new NSString ("UMRET_NO_READER");
   case UMRET_SDK_BUSY : return new NSString ("UMRET_SDK_BUSY");
   case UMRET_ALREADY_CONNECTED : return new NSString ("UMRET_ALREADY_CONNECTED");
   case UMRET_NOT_CONNECTED : return new NSString ("UMRET_NOT_CONNECTED");
   case UMRET_LOW_VOLUME : return new NSString ("UMRET_LOW_VOLUME");
   case UMRET_UF_INVALID_STR : return new NSString ("UMRET_UF_INVALID_STR");
   case UMRET_UF_NO_FILE : return new NSString ("UMRET_UF_NO_FILE");
   case UMRET_UF_INVALID_FILE : return new NSString ("UMRET_UF_INVALID_FILE");
   default: return new NSString ("<unknown code>");
   }
}
```

The other defines should be converted into C# static, e.g.

```
static public NSString UMLOG_ERROR = new NSString ("[UM Error] ");
static public NSString UMLOG_WARNING = new NSString ("[UM Warning] ");
static public NSString UMLOG_INFO = new NSString ("[UM Info] ");
```

Again you might want to use C# `string` (and turn them into `const` too).

Comment: But this code, where I should put it, in ApiDefinition.cs file, StructsAndEnums.cs or another?

Comment: @DATI.Investigation It's not part of the bindings, it's an helper method (so it's optional, nothing depends on it for the native library to work). Put it inside your application (if you need it) or inside `StructsAndEnums.cs` since that file will be part of the final code (unlike `ApiDefinition.cs` which is compiled into *generated* code).